# How to check tableview cell is row or section in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

In objective C i used to check like below

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    if (!indexPath.row)  {
         NSLog(@"section");
    }  else  {
         NSLog(@"row");
    }
}
```

How to do the same with Swift?

Comment: Just translate the same code for swift. Look up the functions in Apple Documentation.

Comment: That method is always called for a row selection; Your Objective-C code simply checks for row 0 being selected.

Comment: every time when this method runs, indexpath will tell you which section's row is clicked.

Comment: I tried translating with a tool, got translated as **if !indexPath.row**. Getting compile error. :( **Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Bool'** tried converting to bool, but result is not as what expected.

Comment: I think you're confusing headers with sections? Every indexpath has a row and a section.

Comment: You need to explicitly compare against 0 in Swift  - `if indexPath.row == 0`

Comment: I think you have a wrong implementation of Table View here. When you select a cell it always invokes `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. May be you are treating the first cell as a header and have a different cell, if so then just simply check for `indexPath.row == 0`

Comment: @GoodSp33d Got my mistake. :) Thankyou!!

Comment: @Paulw11 it worked!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**indexPath.row** it didn't meant a section. You can get the section index by writing **indexPath.section**. Just think of an 2D array. Every section has it's own row. Just think of it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Swift has no automatic conversion of integers to Booleans. You need to make the test explicit: `if indexPath.row != 0 { ... }`